# How to view legend next to matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a plot in matplotlib, which has a lot of lines. I've got a legend which is therefore rather extensive and I placed it next to my plot using the following code:

```
fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('small')
plt.legend(variablelist, loc=0, prop = fontP, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0))
plt.savefig(filename+'.png')
```

The result is as follows:
[image]

As you can see however, the legend is cut off on the right. Is there a way that I can create more space on the right side of the image so that I can see the full legend?

All tips are welcome!

In response to @mmgp I posted the following code below. As you can see by his answer I forgot to add `bbox_inches='tight'` to the savefig part. So for future readers to have a fully working code I just added the `bbox_inches='tight'` in the code below, which makes it work perfectly well.. :) :

```
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

mylist = []
for a in range(10):
    mylist.append([])
    for b in range(10):
        mylist[a].append(random())
        
x = range(len(mylist))
for enum, i in enumerate(mylist):
    plt.plot(x, mylist[enum], label='label_'+str(enum))

plt.grid(b=True)
fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('small')

variablesList = []
for i in range(10):
    variablesList.append('label_'+str(i))

legenda = plt.legend(variablesList, loc=0, prop = fontP, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0))
plt.savefig('testplot.png', bbox_extra_artists=[legenda], bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Have you tried a different figure size?

Comment: @user948652 - Yes I also added the following: plt.figure(figsize=(15,15)). That however, simply gives an large empty plot. I wouldn't know why that is.. :S

Comment: What happens if you use `bbox_extra_artists=[l]` as a new parameter in `plt.savefig` where `l` is the return of `plt.legend` ?

Comment: @mmgp - I added it but nothing special happens. The plot still comes out the same.

Comment: Can you include a fully working code ? A small one.

Comment: @mmgp - I added a full working code. I tried to keep it as small as possible for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost there now, just add a new parameter in `savefig`: `bbox_inches = 'tight'`. That makes matplotlib figure out the needed size for your plot.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I haven't earned enough reputation points to vote you up yet, so here is a big thumbs up from me personally => b (the b is the thumbs up.. :) )

Comment: ;) That is fine. Now, just in case if you want to show this plot (before saving it to a figure), you will need to manually adjust the room for the plot (this is not related to figsize per se).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. And would you be so kind of hinting me in the right direction as to how I would be able to manually adjust the room for the plot?

Comment: Here is one such way: http://pastebin.com/MEDFFDab. You craft a proper axis size.

Comment: You are fast at replying :) Enjoy your plots.